# Problems with rbx1

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running rbx1 with ROS hydro.  This is the nodes I am running: roslaunch rbx1_nav fake_move_base_map_with_obstacles.launch.  It seems to work ok, but I am getting an error:

```
brent@brent:~$ roslaunch rbx1_nav fake_move_base_map_with_obstacles.launch
... logging to /home/brent/.ros/log/aa49dea6-cce1-11e5-9332-5cd99897b32a/roslaunch-brent-3706.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://brent.local:44446/

SUMMARY
========

CLEAR PARAMETERS
 * /move_base/

PARAMETERS
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_th
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_x
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_y
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/angular_sim_granularity
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/dwa
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/escape_vel
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/gdist_scale
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/heading_lookahead
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/heading_scoring
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/heading_scoring_timestep
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/holonomic_robot
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/latch_xy_goal_tolerance
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/max_rotational_vel
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/max_vel_x
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/max_vel_y
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/meter_scoring
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_in_place_vel_theta
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_vel_x
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_vel_y
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/occdist_scale
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/oscillation_reset_dist
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/pdist_scale
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/prune_plan
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/publish_cost_grid_pc
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/sim_granularity
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/sim_time
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/simple_attractor
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/vtheta_samples
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/vx_samples
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/vy_samples
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/xy_goal_tolerance
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/yaw_goal_tolerance
 * /move_base/clearing_rotation_allowed
 * /move_base/controller_frequency
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_frame
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation_radius
 * /move_base/global_costmap/map_type
 * /move_base/global_costmap/max_obstacle_height
 * /move_base/global_costmap/min_obstacle_height
 * /move_base/global_costmap/observation_sources
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_range
 * /move_base/global_costmap/publish_frequency
 * /move_base/global_costmap/raytrace_range
 * /move_base/global_costmap/resolution
 * /move_base/global_costmap/robot_base_frame
 * /move_base/global_costmap/robot_radius
 * /move_base/global_costmap/rolling_window
 * /move_base/global_costmap/scan/clearing
 * /move_base/global_costmap/scan/data_type
 * /move_base/global_costmap/scan/expected_update_rate
 * /move_base/global_costmap/scan/marking
 * /move_base/global_costmap/scan/topic
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static_map
 * /move_base/global_costmap/transform_tolerance
 * /move_base/global_costmap/update_frequency
 * /move_base/local_costmap/global_frame
 * /move_base/local_costmap/height
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inflation_radius
 * /move_base/local_costmap/max_obstacle_height
 * /move_base/local_costmap/min_obstacle_height
 * /move_base/local_costmap/observation_sources
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_range
 * /move_base/local_costmap/publish_frequency
 * /move_base/local_costmap/raytrace_range
 * /move_base/local_costmap/resolution
 * /move_base/local_costmap/robot_base_frame
 * /move_base/local_costmap/robot_radius
 * /move_base/local_costmap/rolling_window
 * /move_base/local_costmap/scan/clearing
 * /move_base/local_costmap/scan/data_type
 * /move_base/local_costmap/scan/expected_update_rate
 * /move_base/local_costmap/scan/marking
 * /move_base/local_costmap/scan/topic
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static_map
 * /move_base/local_costmap/transform_tolerance
 * /move_base/local_costmap/update_frequency
 * /move_base/local_costmap/width
 * /move_base/recovery_behavior_enabled
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /
    map_server (map_server/map_server)
    move_base (move_base/move_base)
    odom_map_broadcaster (tf/static_transform_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://leaf.local:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[move_base-1]: started with pid [3716]
Error:   TF_NAN_INPUT: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "base_link" from authority "/leaf_base" because of a nan value in the transform (nan -nan 0.000000) (nan nan nan nan)
         at line 240 in /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-tf2-0.4.12-0precise-20150328-0804/src/buffer_core.cpp
Error:   TF_NAN_INPUT: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "base_link" from authority "/leaf_base" because of a nan value in the transform (nan -nan 0.000000) (nan nan nan nan)
         at line 240 in /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-tf2-0.4.12-0precise-20150328-0804/src/buffer_core.cpp
Error:   TF_NAN_INPUT: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "base_link" from authority "/leaf_base" because of a nan value in the transform (nan -nan 0.000000) (nan nan nan nan)
         at line 240 in /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-tf2-0.4.12-0precise-20150328-0804/src/buffer_core.cpp
```

Is there a parameter, or parameters that I need to clear?

Thank you,
Brent

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225987/problems-with-rbx1/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2016-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you have another node running (`/leaf_base`), which is publishing Odometry and the transform for `base_link`, but the transform itself contains invalid data. X and Y and NaN (Not A Number), and so is the quaternion which represents rotation.

You should look at your leaf_base node and try to figure out why it's publishing a bad transform.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0